# Add div around input field in ZF2 form

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I am creating a form with Zend Framework 2. I'm using Form class to define form elements like this:

```
class PropertyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name=null)
    {
    ...

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'zip',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => false,
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Zip Code',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'zip',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        )); 

    ...
    }
}
```

And in view I display this form element with the following code:

```
<div class="form-group"><?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('zip')); ?></div>
```

This generates the following HTML output:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to have `<div class="my-class">` around the input field as well. So the desired HTML output would be:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
    <div class="my-class">
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get label and the element itself with two different calls:

For label:

```
<?php echo $this->formLabel($yourForm->get('your_element')); ?>
```

For the elements:

```
<?php echo $this->formSelect($yourForm->get('your_element_select')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formText($yourForm->get('your_element_text')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formRadio($yourForm->get('your_element_radio')); ?>
```

So, for you example, it would be something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('zip')); ?>
    <div class="my-class">
        <?php echo $this->formText($form->get('zip')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```